Why doesn't contravariance apply in certain cases like [b] → Int < a → Int
In the paper Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types, the covariance and contravariance rules are essential when dealing with function types. Covariance applies to the return types of functions, while contravariance applies to the argument types.
In (∀b. [b] → [b]) → Bool < (∀a. a → a) → Bool, the types are compared in a contravariant manner for the input types, which means the more general type must be on the right side. Here, the type a → a is more general than [b] → [b], making the inequality hold.
However, in the case of [b] → Int < a → Int, the argument types are compared contravariantly. For contravariance to hold, the left-hand side argument must be more specific than the right-hand side. Since a can be any type and [b] is a specific type (a list of b), the inequality holds but it should not, for example you can not type annotate length function with a -> Int.
In my opinion, the correct relationship would be a → Int < [b] → Int, and this happens by matching a with [b].
I've been reading some papers on type inference, particularly around co- and contravariant rules for functions. I understand where the contravariant rule comes from, but I don't understand why it doesn't work for examples like [b] → Int < a → Int.
Could someone explain why the contravariant rule doesn't apply here, or if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental?

[so] is for programming and software development questions. This sort of theoretical question is probably better asked on [cs.se]

Why do you believe [b] -> Int < a -> Int? I think neither is < the other; perhaps you meant to include some ∀b. (resp. ∀a.) somewhere? If so, where?

@DanielWagner I think a -> Int < [b] -> Int holds because if you have the following function in haskell:
myfun::a -> Int myfun _ = 5
myfun can also be annotated with [b] -> Int.
and the following also compiles:
myfun::[b] -> Int  myfun _ = 5
but for example length function has the type [b] -> Int but you can not annotate it with a -> Int, so it is counter example for [b] -> Int < a -> Int although if you do the usual contravariant manner in this rule, then you should have a < [b] which holds (anything that can be typed with a can also be typed with [b]).

@SDSD Okay, so the types in question are actually ∀a. (a -> Int) < ∀b. ([b] -> Int).  And this explains the discrepancy, too -- ∀ switches you from one judgment (the subtyping judgment) to another judgment (the instantiation judgment). You in fact have already seen this: notice that we can't have both a < [b] and [b] < a, so a -> a < [b] -> [b] can't satisfy both covariant and contravariant properties at the same time! (What's happening with your first type is we are first switching to contravariant mode, then switching out of subtyping and into instantiation.)

@DanielWagner  That is right, I was not careful with the scope of the forall. I incorrectly considered the type of length as ((∀b. [b]) → Int), which is wrong. The correct type should be ∀b. ([b] → Int).

If you ask me for a way to rearrange lists (∀b. [b] → [b]), I can give you the identity function (∀a. a → a), because it’s the simplest rearranger of lists.
example1 :: forall b. [b] -> [b]
example1 = id @[b]

If you want a predicate about identity functions ((∀a. a → a) → Bool)—which is really no better than a constant Boolean—then I can get away with giving you a predicate about list-rearrangers ((∀b. [b] → [b]) → Bool), because I know you’ll only ever call it on the identity function.
example2 :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Bool
example2 = reverses

reverses :: (forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Bool
reverses f = f @Int [1, 2, 3] == [3, 2, 1]

If you want a function that computes an integer from a single list of values of any type (∀b. [b] → Int), I can give you a function that doesn’t use its argument, and just returns a constant integer (∀a. a → Int).
example3 :: forall b. [b] -> Int
example3 = const @[b] @Int 789

If you ask for a constant function, I can’t give you length, because it does examine its argument.
nonexample4 :: forall a. a -> Int
nonexample4 = length  -- error

But if what you’re asking for is a function that computes an integer from a source of lists of any element type ((∀b. [b]) → Int), the only thing those lists can be is the empty list [], so unlike length, this is as good as a constant integer function.
example5 :: (forall b. [b]) -> Int
example5 xs = 456
  where
    noInts = xs @Int
    noChars = xs @Char
    noVoids = xs @Void

example4 :: forall a. a -> Int
example4 = example5

Moreover, if you ask for a function that makes an integer from a magical wellspring of anything I want ((∀a. a) → Int), then I can play make-believe all I want, but I know that well is dry—you’ll never actually call it with anything but bottom.
example6 :: (forall a. a) -> Int
example6 magic = anyInt + ord anyChar
  where
    anyInt = magic @Int
    anyChar = magic @Char
    anyVoid = magic @Void  -- oh no

So in the end the variance depends not only on function arrows, but also quantifiers:

(∀a. a → Int) < (∀b. [b] → Int) but
((∀b. [b]) → Int) < ((∀a. a) → Int)


@JonPordy I have a question: does this subsumption hold? ((∀a. a) → (∀a. a)) < (∀a. a → a)
Based on the spec and skolemization rules, it seems like it should not hold, but it does in Haskell. For example, I can annotate the function below with the type (∀a. a → a):
fun undefined = undefined


@NisNis: No, fun undefined = undefined shadows the top-level undefined :: forall a. a, so this is equivalent to fun x = x, which is the identity. With deep subsumption, fun :: (forall a. a) -> (forall a. a) is equivalent to fun :: forall a1. (forall a2. a2) -> a1, so fun x = x typechecks because x is instantiated as x @a1. But you can’t write fun1 :: (forall a. a) -> (forall a. a); fun1 x = x; fun2 :: forall a. a -> a; fun2 = fun1.

I see. Thank you so much.
